# Eclipse Issue for Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, mobile-application

I am going to start the Android Mobile APP development. But i cant able to start the process further, because In my first form (FILE->NEW->Android Application) I didnt get the recent version in "Target SDK" and "Compile with"  is empty in Eclipse.

Attached the screens. Suggest me what can i do for next step?.

[image]
[image]

- Kumaran

Comment: Have you installed the available update of Android SDK Tools?

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse window  - >Preference -> Left side click on android -> Browse the android sdk home directory.as like bellow image..-.Apply -> ok...Done.  After that create the project.

[image]

Comment: I checked in My Side. No option listed in the above mentioned dialog box. But i mentioned SDK location was correct. I dont know how we can get it from SDK and Downloaded the recent updates by using SDK Manager.

Comment: u need to download the android versions. Go to windows-> Click on SDK Manager i will opens window select android version download. after that do the above step

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse do this :

Window-> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location now give actual path and apply then OK.

Now you would be able to select compile with.